# SQL Azure - Change Database Edition on Master

Tags: azure, web, azure-sql-database

When dropping one of the databases on our SQL Azure account and afterwards creating a new updated version of it, this was set to Business 50GB (yes, I know you can change the edition using a simple script). So far so good.

However our master database is still set to Web edition, and I don't know how to change it, as the aforementioned script does not work here.

My challenge is, that I cannot drop the server and create a new do to our current infrastructure provider who is very conservative and not willing to change firewall and DNS to the new server.

Is there a simple way to change the edition on master - or will Azure do it automatically?

My worries is, that the Web Edition (MASTER DATABASE) maybe outgrow the 5GB limit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you think you might outgrow the Master database in SQL Azure. First of all your Master Database is read-only. And it is used for storing information about all other databases (which can be up to 149, not a big number), database logins and some statistics.

From "[Windows Azure SQL Database Provisioning Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336227.aspx)":

> The provisioning process creates a read-only master database
>   automatically. The master database keeps track of which logins have
>   permission to create databases or other logins. You must be connected
>   to the master database whenever you CREATE, ALTER, or DROP logins or
>   databases. The master database also provides SQL Database usage
>   metrics that you can view.

Frankly, If you ever reach the 5G of the Master DB in Windows Azure, just contact the support, but I doubt it will happen soon.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My worries was plain and simple from the logic of having identical editions on SQL Azure. For instance, our staging environment holds a 1GB Web Edition with a 5GB Web Edition master database. Can you see why I might be worried, since the Business edition in our production is set to 50GB with a 5GB Web Edition master. The master holds all information regarding indexes, database, tables, constraints and so forth, right?

Comment: I don't think there is a place to worry about the master database, as it is auto managed by the fabric.Even if it holds information about indexes/tables/etc.  - etc, database object in general, it is just the meta data! The actual indexes take place (occupy space) in your actual database, not in the master db.

Comment: Okay, I will mark your answer as usefull then .. again, I was just curious why SQL Azure did not name the editions equally. Thanks, mate.

Comment: Well, this naming (Web/Business) has always frustrated me, as it does not distinguish the editions by any meaningful way. Not to mention that an year ago you could have 5G Web Edition as well as 5G Business Edition DB...